# Iron-router & PathFor

Tags: meteor, iron-router

When I am using route without params, I've got normal pathFor in my template. But when I am adding some "slug", like this:

```
@route "pagesSlug",
  path: "/page/:_slug"
  name: "page"
```

And got error in console:

```
You called Router.path for a route named page but that route doesn't seem to exist. Are you sure you created it?
```

No change when I add/remove name.
I've got empty {{pathFor ... in my template, and urlFor too empty.

In this case:

```
@route "articlesList",
  path: "/articles"
  waitOn: ()->
    Meteor.subscribe 'articles'
```

I've got href="/articles" - no problem.

Update: Meteor 0.9.4, and 0.9.4 of Iron-Router.

Comment: Which iron-router version are you using? 0.9.4 or 1.0.0-pre4 ?

Comment: 0.9.4. Sorry for "latest"

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of the route function is the name of the route. Your route name is `pagesSlug`

To get the path by the `pathFor` helper, you need to also pass the parameter _slug

```
{{pathFor "pagesSlug" _slug="xxxx"}}
```

Comment: I read this in manual. But this doesn't work.
In tempalte {{pathFor 'pagesSlug' }}  is empty